# Unable to use Test time-out at suite level

Tags: maven, testng

I have a situation where i need set some time limit for each test.E.g. 1 min. Somehow setting it at testng.xml does not seem to work.

I tried setting it at main testng.xml file & also in the suite xml files. Neither of them worked.

I used below testng.xml which has multiple suite-files like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" time-out="60000" verbose="3">
 <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="allTests.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="aaa-aaa.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="bbb-aaa.xml"></suite-file>
    </suite-files>
</suite>

my aaa-aaa.xml looks like below

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="allTests Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
    <test name="XXX tests" >
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="1111-111" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
             <package name="com.xxx.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

It does not error.

Answer (score 0):

It did not work for me when i added time-out attribute in suite of suites xml (testng.xml). but it is working when time-out is added inside individual suite-file. Result is same when i execute from testng.xml and maven test. I am using testng version 6.14.3 in my POM.xml

Below are suit files :

testng.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="3">
 <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="suit1.xml"/>
        <suite-file path="suit2.xml"/>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

suite1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suitone" time-out="6000" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
    <test name="XXX tests" >
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="1111-111" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
             <package name="pkgone.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

suite2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suittwo" time-out="7000" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
    <test name="XXX tests" >
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="2222-222" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
             <package name="pkgtwo.*"></package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

TestClasses :

Test1.java:

```
package pkgone;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test1 
{
@Test(groups= "1111-111")
public void test1()
{
    System.out.println("suit1 test1");
}
@Test
public void test2() throws InterruptedException
{
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println("suit1 test2");
}
}
```

Test2.java:

```
package pkgone;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test2 
{
    @Test
    public void test2_1()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello 2_1");
    }
    @Test
    public void test2_2() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Hello 2_2");
    }
}
```

Test3.java:

```
package pkgtwo;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test3
{
    @Test(groups= "2222-222")
    public void test3_1()
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
    @Test
    public void test3_2() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        System.out.println("suite 2 test 3");
    }
}
```

Test4.java:

```
package pkgtwo;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test4 
{
    @Test
    public void test4_1() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Hello 4_1");
    }
    @Test
    public void test4_2()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello 4_2");
    }
}
```